# Impossible to read / delete some files

Tags: filesystems, ext3, ext4, data-recovery

How can I fix a message like this (read after a dmesg command)?

```
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119198
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119217
EXT4-fs warning (device hdb1): ext4_unlink: Deleting nonexistent file (119196), 0
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119201
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
```

It seems impossible to retrieve (or delete) a bunch of files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a corrupt ext4 filesystem. What kernel are you using?

Did you try a filesystem check, i.e. `umount /dev/hdb1`, then `e2fsck /dev/hdb1`? What is the output?

If `/dev/hdb1` cannot be umounted (because it is needed by the system, e.g. `/` or `/usr`), you should try to mount read-only. If that is also not possible, you have to boot a rescue system.

(Would have posted this as a comment, but I'm lacking reputation points.)

Comment: after a scan with e2fsck, it's possible to rescue /delete files and directories. But this is out of my scope, cause i'm tryng to recover a directory that contains a db schema